# PHP: Which value must display_errors have, if I have a custom error-handling function?

Tags: php, function

my existing code is:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 ini_set('log_errors', 1);
 ini_set('error_log', LOG_PATH."error.log");
```

So currently my erros will be displayed and logged into error.log. Fine, but now I´d like to have a custom error-handling function so that the user don´t see informations about the system which do not concern him.
So if I use set_error_handler is it necessary to set display_errors to "On" that the errors will be called to the error-handling-function? Which value must display_errors have, if I have a custom error-handling function?

Comment: Did you try official [set_error_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) documentation page ?

Comment: Just google "php custom error handling" and php.net gives you the answer on the first result..

Comment: Sorry that didn´t answere my question

Comment: He used off but gave no reason for it

Comment: `" error_reporting() settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless - however you are still able to read the current value of error_reporting and act appropriately."`

Comment: Yeah, but that is not the answer to my question. I´ll explain it to you: PHP logs the errors without any self made function, so I´d like only to avoid that the error messages appear to the user, but still log the errors as they would appear on the page. If I use set_error_handler PHP will not log the errors anymore. My question is does this has something todo with display_errors-value or something else?

Comment: Because the sentence you´ve described above doesn´t has something todo with display_errors, only error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); will have no effect!

Comment: I would imagine turning off display_errors would sort it and your custom function would still be called. I've never done something like this, but surely you could have just turned it off, written an error and tested it? It shouldn't be very hard to just test in your code

Comment: I already tested it, but that didn´t help me. Ok my result: Sure I can turn off display_errors and almost everything has been achieved what I wanted: The user will not see error-informations and the error will be logged, but the user will get no information that an error occured. So this is the only problem I hoped to solve with set_error_handler. If I define a custom handler it seems to deactive display_errors and log_errors, so I have to log it into my own handler. Is that the only way?

Comment: Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you use *set_error_handler* your custom function will be called regardless to the *display_errors* value.